# JavaScript regex over multiple lines?

Tags: regex

```
START Curabitur mollis, dolor ut rutrum consequat, arcu nisl ultrices diam, adipiscing aliquam ipsum metus id velit. Aenean vestibulum gravida felis, quis bibendum nisl 

euismod ut.END

1 START xxx END

2 START xxx END

3 START xxx END

4 START xxx END

5 START xxx END

6 START xxx END
```

Hi, i want to use reg expression to get the text within each (START) and (END) where there can be a newline within the (START) and (END).

i tried using this expression

```
(START)(.*[\S\s]*)(END)
```

but it will highlight all the text, including those not within (START) and (END).

How can i get the text within each (START) and (END), with newline in between?

Comment: Just use lazy matching - `START([\s\S]*?)END`.

Comment: See http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap

Answer (score 0):

The `.*` part is redudant in your pattern since `[\s\S]*` match the same text.

Besides, you need to use lazy quantifier `*?` after `[\s\S]` in order to make it match as few characters as possible between `START` and `END`. Read more about [greedy trap at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap).

Use

```
/START([\s\S]*?)END/g
```

or

```
/START([^]*?)END/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE5mH6/1)